# Submenu animation "pops up"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a menu with sub items inside it. In order to make animation effect I want, I need to retrieve sub-menu **width**,**height** and **height of its first-child**. Now my animation works ,but sometimes my sub-menu just "pops up" (it doesn't animate its **width** ).

Here is **[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNxJ4/)** of the problem.

http://www.vasinternetposao.com/wordpressdevelopment/wp-content/themes/override/images/submenu_problem.png

I am using this code:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function () {

    j('ul.nav').removeClass('nav').addClass('jnav'); //Add jquery Class to our menu 

    j('ul.jnav li').hover(function () {
        if (j(this).children('ul:first').hasClass('jsub-menu')) { //Let's check if "jsub-menu" Class is here
            return false; //If it is ("jsub-menu" here) don't SlideDown...
        } else { //Else slide down if no class
            j(this).find('ul.sub-menu:first').not(':animated').slideDown(500);
        }

    }, function () {
        j(this).find('ul:first').slideUp(500, function () {
            j(this).removeClass('jsub-menu').addClass('sub-menu');
            j(this).css({
                'height': '',
                'width': ''
            });
        });

    });

    j('ul.jnav ul.sub-menu a').hover(function () {
        j(this).addClass('active');

        if (j('.active').next('ul.sub-menu').length) { //If submenu exist...
            j('.active').next('ul.sub-menu').css({
                'visibility': 'hidden',
                'opacity': '0',
                'display': 'block'
            }); //Show it so we can read its:

            var get_width = j('.active').next('ul.sub-menu').outerWidth(true); //WIDTH
            var get_height_of_first_child = j('.active').next('ul.sub-menu').children('li:first').outerHeight(true); //HEIGHT of its First Child
            var get_submenu_height = j('.active').next('ul.sub-menu').outerHeight(true); //HEIGHT of our menu

            j('.active').next('ul').removeClass('sub-menu') //Remove class from menu, add another class apply HEIGHT of FIRST CHILD and hide it again...
            .addClass('jsub-menu').css({
                'visibility': '',
                'opacity': '',
                'height': get_height_of_first_child + 'px',
                'width': '0'
            });
            j('.active').next('.jsub-menu').animate({
                width: get_width
            }, 1000, function () { //Animate WIDTH

                j('.active').next('.jsub-menu').animate({
                    height: get_submenu_height
                }, 1000); //callback animate HEIGHT
            });
        } //End if    
    }, function () {
        j('.active').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

I think that this is happening because my **Slide Up/Down** animations are conflicting with my **animate with/height** functions but I am not sure. I have tried to solve it by adding `stop()`,`stop(true,true)`,`stop(true,false)` in numerous combinations but failed. I am trying to solve this for days now so you stackers are my only hope. Please help! 

Thank you!!

Comment: Is this happening in any browser or only a specific one?

Comment: Looks like it happens in all browsers:(

Comment: Yeah, I just did, and it doesn't really happen to me on Chrome...

Comment: It looks like I cannot replicate the error, but you might want to consider using CSS animations instead - they are known for being smoother than JS animations

Comment: Hmm can you do me a one last favour and try to change animation duration to 5000 and then do the hover while the menu is expanding? Because on my rig it doesn't work well even in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to replicate the error.

I wrote this code for you, to replace the code you have for the animation.

```
var animating = false;
function animate($elm, options, callback) {        
    if (animating) 
        return;

    animating = true;
    $elm.animate(options, 1000, function() {
        animating = false;

        if (callback != undefined)
            callback();
    });        
}
```

Call it like this, from inside your hover callback.

```
animate(j('.active').next('.jsub-menu'), 
        {
            'width': get_width,
            'height' : get_submenu_height
        });
```

Basically, it checks if another animation is already running, in which case it doesn't start it. The Flag is set to false when the animation stopped, and let's other animations go on.

You can also pass a callback to do something after the animation is completed, but in your case you don't need it, because you can animate the height and width in the same time.

I tested it for like a minute and it looked pretty smooth.

Here is the updated feedle: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielcatalin/TNxJ4/1/

**P.S.** You may also want to use the $ sign instead of 'j' for jQuery wrappers.